# DS3 weapon with all base effects

Tags: dark-souls-3

I have Chaos Drakeblood Greatsword and it has all but Dark effect. Is it possible to get to a weapon that would have all the effects?

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. Additionally, this weapon also does not deal hollow damage either (increased damaged vs hollowed enemies).